# Motorbike storage questions (gsxr 1000 2018)

Tags: motorcycle, oil, storage

I don’t have a garage and I’m storing my bike outside. Temperatures during the daylight are around 90-115F max. There’s no much shade around the bike but it gets morning and afternoon’s sun beating.

I got a quality cover for the bike (Oxford stormex), cleaned the bike, changed oil, taped the intake, plugged the muffler, removed the battery & taped the battery terminals on the bike too.

I also treated my gas tank with fresh fuel with Starbrite fuel stabilizer. And I overused it just in case (company says overdose is not harmful). I made sure to top up the tank until it’s full.

I’m just wondering:

1. Would the fuel go bad due to high summer temperature?
2. Would the fuel evaporate and leave gunk during the next 6 months?
3. After storage, should I drain the treated fuel and pour in fresh fuel after inspecting the gas tank?
4. Is it safe to use bore scope inside the gas tank just for extra peace of mind?
5. Is oil change recommended?
6. Finally, my bike has 1700miles and I’m thinking of switching to fully synthetic oil. Would that hurt or I should wait until 3000 miles!

Cheers!!

Comment: when is its first scheduled maintenance? Also, I assume your are from Britian right?

Comment: Currently I live in Dubai. It’s summer and temperatures are high during middays.

Comment: 5) People recommend oil change if it is dirty. If you have ever changed the oil, I wouldn't bother. If you are still with the stock oil, I probably would. The first oil change is much earlier than others for a reason.
6) I don't think it would. Synthetic oil is simply more "balanced". 
1-2) I don't think fuel would but the additives probably will. I have no idea what would the best action be.